# How to retrieve Ext.data.JsonStore data in sencha

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have  the following code -

```
var options = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            model: 'options_model',
            data: [
                { id: 1, option1: 'Alope', status1: 'true',option2: 'Option2', status2: 'false',option3: 'Option3', status: 'false',option4: 'Option4', status4: 'false' }
                  ]
        });
```

Now how can I retrieve  data of option ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you put your data into maybe a filename.json file (this is to maintain the scalability and integrity of your code).

Anyway, wherever it is you store your data, this is the code you need:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'path_to_ur_json_file_wrt_html_file/filename.json',    //in my case it was data/xyz.json  since my folder layout was : abc.html, app, data, lib, stylesheets; and my data.json was in the data folder :)
    timeout:3000,      //how long it shud try to retrieve data in ms
    method:'GET',
    success: function(xhr) {
        jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(xhr.responseText);
        var data4u = jsonData.data[0].option1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `JsonStore` is not really a class to use. It's internal to Sencha and may be removed at any time. You should use `Ext.data.Store` instead.

Second, many of the out-of-the-box components in Sencha receive a store as confguration options so you don't have to worry about the inner workings.

Finally, if you do need to access store's data, you can do so by using `each`, `getAt` or `find` methods, depending on your needs and the way you want to access your data (random access, sequential or search).

I suggest you to go over this documentation:[Sencha 1.1 Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)